# Regex to validate email format or some template string

Tags: regex, validation

I have an email address field which is supposed to accept either an email address or a template string like this. `{TemplateString<NUMBER>}`

Required validations

1. Either an email format `^\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b$` this is fine don't get carried away too much here :|
2. OR the template format like `{TemplateString<NUMBER>}`

   1. Start with `{`
   2. Ends with `}`
   3. The character(s) before the ending `}` should be a number

Example

`{HelloThere5}`, `{HowAreYou86}`, `{notcasesensitive9887}` are valid and `{ThisIsInVal88d}` is not.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you include your attempt on that OR part? You might not be far off a solution yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the pattern you want for the template is the following:

```
^\{[a-z]+\d+\}$
```

So we can merge it into your existing email regex like this:

```
^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$|^\{[a-z]+\d+\}$
```

Comment: Can you help me validate the total number of `{` to 1? ie it should only contain 1 template string

Comment: @niksmac - Sorry I made a mistake. I updated the merged regex in my answer. You could also use `^(?:[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$|\{[a-z]+\d+\})$` which has the same effect.